# Using AngularJS's $http.put method

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, http

I am attempting to use AngularJS to update some data using the $http.put method.  However, I have tried several variations on calling this method and it has repeatedly failed to call the put method in my controller - or, if it does, it creates a new entity rather than updating the old data.  Here is my code:

(I know the rest of my api works as post and get work fine for cars)

CarController.cs

```
    public void Put(int CarId, [FromBody] Car c)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CarController.Put() Called");
        c.CarId = CarId;
        if (!_repo.UpdateCar(c) || !_repo.Save())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
```

Repository ("_repo"):

```
    public bool UpdateCar(Car car)
    {
        if (car == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("car");
        }
        int index = _ctx.Cars.ToList().FindIndex(c => c.CarId == car.CarId);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        _ctx.Cars.ToList().RemoveAt(index);
        _ctx.Cars.Add(car);
        return true;

    }
```

AngularJS script:

```
var _linkPersonAndCar = function(person, car) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    alert("_linkPersonAndCar()\nPerson = " + JSON.stringify(person) + "\nCar = " + JSON.stringify(car));

    //Update car
    car.persons.splice(0, 0, person);

    alert("_linkPersonAndCar() attempting put");

    $http.put("/api/cars/"+car.carId, car)
        .then(function ()
        {
            alert("_linkPersonAndCar() - Success!");
            deferred.resolve();
        },
        function ()
        {
            alert("_linkPersonAndCar() - Failure updating car");
            deferred.reject();
        });

    alert("_linkPersonAndCar() - Complete");

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: You say that it doesn't call the put method, but when it does, it creates a new entity.  Which is it?

Comment: Between this and your other post, you are putting too much into the question.  They both seem to be about (1) using angular to call a controller method and (2) why Entity Framework is inserting an item instead of updating.  Debug your code and start isolating these problems into separate questions.

Comment: The problem is that every approach I have taken has done something different and none do what I want so I was hoping to make sure that I wasn't doing something wrong out of ignorance for *this* method while my other post is asking if there's some way I haven't tried yet that will work

Comment: And consider using the $resource service as it will help out with a lot of the boilerplate for calling a REST API.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your questions because without more information no one can know whether it's a problem with the controller and model binding, the angular setup, or your entity framework code.

Comment: Ok.  At the very least could someone explain where the parameter "[FromBody] Car c" is supposed to come from in the controller.  Looking at the documentation for $http.put() it says the first param is a url and the second is "data", yet when I use the call in angular ("$http.get("api/cars/"+car.carId, car)"), the put method in the controller isn't even called (if I just use the URL c is null).

Comment: If you hit F12 in Chrome, you can see what is being passed in the network tab.  Try this passing the car as data.  If you see the error (it will be red), you can click it and see what the response from the server is, which will give you some clues about what is going wrong.  Again, I recommend you wrap this bit up in a new, more specific question.

Comment: Ok I'm going to post a new question that will try to focus this one down to the essentials

Comment: ... Apparently I have to wait 90 mins to post again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, see my comments for advice on breaking up this into separate questions.  But I see at least one problem with your EF code:

```
_ctx.Cars.ToList().RemoveAt(index);
```

Calling ToList() creates a list disconnected from the provider (EF Context), and creates an in-memory list.  You then remove the item from that list, which will not accomplish anything, since you don't use that list in any subsequent code.  This will not delete the entity from the database, which I think was your intent.  In any case, you want to update the existing car, not delete and re-add it (at least that's my assumption).

```
_ctx.Cars.Add(car);
```

This will always add a new car.

You want something more like:

```
var ctxCar = _ctx.Cars.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CarId = car.CarId);

if (ctxCar == null)
{
  return false;
}

//here you want map properties from your parameter to your context's car
ctxCar.Property1 = car.Property1;
//etc.

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `_ctx` an EF context? If so, **attaching** should work:

```
// connect to context
_ctx.Cars.Attach(car);
// check for updated info
var entry = _ctx.Entry(car);
entry.Property(e => e.NumberOfDoors).IsModified = true;
// save changes
_ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Otherwise, Phil is correct:

```
_ctx.Cars.Add(car);
```

will always give you a new record